# Is there a random seed for strings in Python

Tags: python, string, random

Is there something similar to the random seed number generator in Python for strings?

Let's say I want to choose a random sequence of characters from the string `'abcdefg'`- if I use `''.join(random.choice('abcdefg'))` I will get a different result every time. How do I go about getting a random seed sequence of strings from these characters similar to that of `random.seed()` function in Python?

Comment: You can `seed` the RNG exactly the same for this usage; what exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to get a string back from the function, but what I get is a float value. For instance: random.seed('abcd') will return 0,3 if I use random.random()

Comment: That is **not** how `seed` works, please re-read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use random.seed. From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed)

> Initialize the basic random number generator.

So every function working with random, use the seed, even choice:

```
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> random.choice('abcdef')
'a'
>>> random.choice('abcdef')
'f'
>>> random.choice('abcdef')
'e'
>>> random.seed(1)
>>> random.choice('abcdef')
'a'
>>> random.choice('abcdef')
'f'
>>> random.choice('abcdef')
'e'
```

Answer (score -2):

This is my first post so take it with a grain of salt.

You can use randint, remove and append

```
myString = 'abcdefg'

1. create an array numBank with length 0->6 (the length of string 'abcdefg')
2. use randint to get a random int in numBank
3. use that random integer as an index for myString[i] and append myString[i] to a new array
4. use remove.numBank(i) to delete the number from the numBank
5. use randint to get another random number from numBank
6. repeat steps 3-5 until numBank is empty
```

This should get the job done even though there is probably a more efficient way of doing it. I hope this helps you come up with the right code to get the job done. Good luck!